# Best Way to migrate code from magento 1 to magento 2?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

I am trying to migrate magento 1 website to magento 2 i am able to migrate data but i want to know is it possible to migrate code also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The we have a migration tool kit in git hub

The toolkit covers migration of the following aspects of the Magento code:

```
**Module directory structure
Layout XML files
Config XML files
PHP files**
```

This will help you to get a over all skeleton of m1 module.
[For Tool Go To](https://github.com/magento/code-migration)